# Javascript errors in Selenium IEDriverServer

Tags: selenium, iedriverserver

I have a selenium test engine written in C#.
We're constantly getting failures due to `IEDriverServer`.
The exception only states

> "javascript error"

It is never consistent, but happens more than enough to make a "production" use of the engine impossible.
I don't know, maybe this is the best stability selenium can offer?
Or how could I fix this?

Comment: Share screen shot of proper error and please prefer not to ask opinionated questions. You can ask the about the possibles reasons for the error you are facing.

Comment: Feel free to remove the question. Ill find the answer elsewhere